# How to get a 3D vector in the same direction as another vector limited by an angle?

Tags: math, vector, 3d, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

If I have two 3D vectors as shown by the blue and red vector in the image below, where the red vector is at an angle of more than 20 degrees from the blue vector, how could I calculate a new vector (green in the example) that is exactly 20 degrees away from the blue, in the same direction as the red one? It doesn't need to have the same length as the red one, ideally it would be a unit (normalized direction) vector. How would I do this if the arbitrary angle limit would be a variable named x?

[image: Example image]

For context: I am making a video game where I get the location of where the player is aiming and draw a Linetrace from the weapon muzzle to the player aim location. However if this Linetrace is more than x degrees off from the actual direction the weapon is pointing I want the weapon to fire x degrees in the direction of the players aim so that it cant just shoot sidewards.

If you are able to give the answer as unreal engine 5.x blueprints that would be amazing but not necessary. I can just convert the pure math to blueprints myself.

Comment: More than 20 degrees... how? it's a 3D vector, unlike 2D you _need_ to specify over which axis, or in which plane, that rotation happens. At the very least, show the red and green x/y/z components too, so that folks can understand the image you're showing.

Comment: 20 degrees between the vectors in general along all axes, if you take the arccosine of the dot product you get the angle between two vectors on the plane they are both on, even in 3D space. The green vector has to be coplanar with the red and blue. I described that a bit badly by saying 'in the same direction'. @MBo 's solution worked perfectly for what I wanted.

Comment: Rephrasing the problem often helps reveal the solution: described as having two vectors that form a plane, and wanting to find a third vector in that plane at a specific angle away from one of them, now tells us (and you, of course) that you're really just trying to rotate a vector in a plane (and then what that plane is, and even what angle the rotation is, becomes mostly irrelevant for the math to work) and suddenly google will be more than happy to find you quite a few really good answers in the first few search results =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fas as I understand the problem, `in the same direction` here denotes that vectors `Blue`, `Read` and `Green` are coplanar.

So you can use spherical linear interpolation [(SLERP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp).
Normalize vectors `B` and `R`, get angle between them

```
Ω = acos(B.dot.R)
```

and build `G` (here `θ=20 degrees`)

```
G = B * sin(Ω - θ)/sin(Ω)   +   R * sin(θ)/sin(Ω)
```

---

Alternative is to make rotation axis perpendicular to `B` and `R` and rotate `B` around it (looks more complex, but perhaps your library has appropriate functions)

```
R = B x R (vector product)
M = matrix to rotate B around R by 20 degrees
G = M * B
```

Comment: Thanks, your SLERP solution works perfectly! (Edit: And yea I meant the vectors are all coplanar by 'in the same direction')